# How To Append String To Dictionary in Python within Forloop

Tags: python

i need to append a value of string to a specific key in dictionary in python within forloop, and if the data in forloop is empty then give the value of empty string which i'm not able to get it right, here is some of the code,

```
top100 = {}

for product in product_list:
    title = product.xpath('a[@class="someClass"]/text()') # LIST of 100
    price = product.xpath('div[@class="someClass"]/text()') # LIST of 100

    # the value in the title is list of 100 title 
    # more like ['title1', 'title2', ...] and so the price [100, 230, ...]


    # how to append each pairs of title and price so i have list of dictionary
    
    top100['title'].append(title)
    top100['price'].append(price)


print( top100)
```

output:

```
KeyError: 'title'
```

but i need something more like:

```
top100 = [{'title': 'title1', 'price': 'price1'}, 
          {'title': 'title2', 'price': 'price2'}
         ]
```

Comment: `top100` should be a `list` not a `dict`?

Comment: Could you not just do ```top100.append({"title":title, "price":price})```?

Comment: Are the results of your `xpath` calls lists, as well?

Comment: oh my bad, but now im getting "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: but the title and price was list

Comment: That would be because of ```top100["title"]    top100["price"]```

Comment: yeah the result of `xpath` is list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the answer i was able to find my own solution,

```
top100 = []
for product in product_list:
    titles = product.xpath('a[@class="someLink"]/text()')
    prices = product.xpath('div[@class="somePrice"]/text()')

    for title, price, in zip(titles, prices):
        top100.append({'title':title, 'price':price})
```

output:

```
top100 = [{'title': 'title1', 'price': '100'}, 
          {'title': 'title2', 'price': '200'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `top 100` variable should be a list, then append a dictionary

```
top100 = []

for product in product_list:
    title = product.xpath('a[@class="someClass"]/text()') # LIST of 100
    price = product.xpath('div[@class="someClass"]/text()') # LIST of 100

    
    top100.append({'title':title,'price':price})


print( top100)
```

Comment: You wrote in the last sentences that you need something more like this

Comment: So would ```for i in range(len(title)): list.append({"title":title[i], "price": price[i]})``` work??

Comment: since title and price was list so the output that i had is:

    `{'title': ['someTitle'], 'price': ['400']}`

Comment: but i want something more like`{title: 'someTitle', 'price': 'someprice'}`

Comment: So you mean the `product_list` only contain one value ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `top100` a list with many nested dictionaries, with the following code:

```
top100 = []
for product in product_list:
    title = product.xpath('a[@class="someClass"]/text()') # LIST of 100
    price = product.xpath('div[@class="someClass"]/text()') # LIST of 100
    top100.append({'title':title,'price':price})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here for the another version of result

```
top100 = {'title':[],'price':[]}

for product in product_list:
    title = product.xpath('a[@class="someClass"]/text()') # LIST of 100
    price = product.xpath('div[@class="someClass"]/text()') # LIST of 100

    
    top100['title'].append(title)
    top100['price'].append(price)


print( top100)
```

This should output

```
{'title':[..., ..., ... ],'price':[..., ..., ...]}
```